# DOMDocument60 Node List

Tags: xml, vb6

I am having an issue trying to get the Node List to get populated correctly.

```
Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

Set xmlNodeLst = xmlDoc.selectNodes("TagToGetNodes")
```

This issue is the XML Tag itself looks like this:

```
TagToGetNodes xmlns="http://www.randomlink.com/TagToGetNodes"
```

If this is not in the tag, `xmlns="http://www.randomlink.com/TagToGetNodes` - the code above works 100% of the time.   With that in the tag, fails everytime.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The issue is the Attribute name of `xmlns`.  Name it something else, or remove it entirely as you mentioned, and the code works fine.

Comment: Only kickback is I am getting the XML from a third party - I have no control over the attribute.  I can edit the XML as a text file and eliminate the attribute.  There has to be a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample node has a Namespace.  If you give the Namespace a name:

```
xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:YourName='http://www.randomlink.com/TagToGetNodes'"
```

Then you can modify your XPath to include the given name allowing the nodes to be selected:

```
Set xmlNodeLst = xmlDoc.selectNodes("YourName:TagToGetNodes")
```

Comment: That gave me the value for TagToGetNodes but not the list of tags within that Node List.   TagToGetNotes is first - within it is CompletionCode, ErrorTag, HostResponse.  I can't get the nodes

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.  You definitely pointed me in the right direction.

I did as your said with the Namespace.  I just had to fix my loop.  I ended up looping through .childNodes of the Namespace and it worked great.

Thanks for your help.  You're a life saver